# Custom CSS for CKEditor toolbar

Tags: ckeditor, editor, wysiwyg

How do I create a custom stylesheet for the CKEditor (toolbar, etc.) and load it through the config?

I tried this but this seems to only change the CSS for the content within the editor, but not the editor itself:

```
config.contentsCss = '/skins/custom/editor.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use CKEditor's config to customise the toolbar, dialogs, etc. The UI of the editor resides at the same level in DOM as main `ckeditor.js` file. Basically put your stylesheet into `<head>` section of your webpage:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
  <link href="/skins/custom/editor.css" rel="stylesheet">
  ...
</head>
```

Be aware of the [specificity of CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).